# File Locked on Flash Drive

Tags: windows, usb, ntfs, usb-flash-drive

I'm completely frustrated. I'm an owner of a OCZ 8GB Rally2 which I've used flawlessly for about 4 months now, and all of a sudden this week I begin getting errors telling me that I can't delete a file due to "make sure the disk is not write-protected, full or and the file is not in-use" dialog. Here's what I've tried:

- Deleting the file using FileASSASSIN (it's worked on everything else but files on this darn flash drive)
- Formatting the flash drive and then restoring the backed up information (I format to NTFS, FYI)

Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 10):

Use [**Unlocker**](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/):

[image]

If that doesn't work, there are alternatives that will remove the file upon reboot, before Windows has a chance to lock them. 2 such programs are:

[**Boot Deleter**](http://software.bootblock.co.uk/?id=bootdeleter):

[image]

[**MoveOnBoot**](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot-Manager-Disk/MoveOnBoot.shtml):

[image]

Comment: Nice screen capture work... I'm impressed =8-)

Comment: +1 because I can't give +2. Really good answer, I can see you've earnt your rep.

Answer (score 2):

When I get this error message, I use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)'s handle-search feature to find which application is holding which resource in the system, so maybe this can help you too.